# Creating a Column in Pandas Dataframe by Calculation using four columns of the dataframe with some math methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas' dataframe that contains a number of features(columns) including two geographical locations with their longitudes and latitudes. That means that the dataframe has two latitudes and two longitudes as columns. My intention is to create a new column in the dataframe that would be the distance between the two geographical locations using their latitudes and longitudes. I defined as function that would calculate the distance as follows:

```
from math import radians, sqrt, atan2, sin, cos

  def distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
     
    # The math module contains a function named
    # radians which converts from degrees to radians.
    lon1a = radians(lon1)
    lon2a = radians(lon2)
    lat1a = radians(lat1)
    lat2a = radians(lat2)
      
    # Haversine formula
    
    dlon = radians(lon2 - lon1)
    dlat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1a) * cos(lat2a) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
 
    
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    r = 6371
      
    # calculate the result
    return(c * r)
```

I applied the function to create the distance column in my dataframe as follows:

```
df.insert(21, 'distance', df.apply(distance(df.resident_latitude, df['#lat_deg'], df.resident_longitude,df['#lon_deg'] ) ))
```

This is the error message I got

[image: Error message]

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
     last)
    <ipython-input-101-68f2bd753640> in <module>
    ----> 1 df.insert(21, 'distance', df.apply(distance(df.resident_latitude, 
    df['#lat_deg'], df.resident_longitude,df['#lon_deg'] ) ))
    <ipython-input-87-cdbbc1795246> in distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2)
          3     # The math module contains a function named
          4     # radians which converts from degrees to radians.
    ----> 5     lon1a = radians(lon1)
          6     lon2a = radians(lon2)
          7     lat1a = radians(lat1)
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
        139         if len(self) == 1:
        140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
    --> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
        142 
        143     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"
    TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I also attempted creating additional columns for **dlon and dlat** as defined in the function above but got the same error message. Another attempt was to use a **lambda** function to create these new columns but got different type error such as **AttributeError** that rows do not have the attribute resident_latitude.

Comment: Please can you provide some data.

Comment: Above link hosts the data and the preliminary etl code. Thanks

Comment: It would be best to pull a sample of the data and add it to your question. Give an example of input data and example of what the output should look like (5 or 6 rows for each should be enough).

Comment: use `numpy` instead of `math`, and then you can pass entire columns if your dataframe to your function and compute all of the values at once

Comment: `resident_latitude | resident_longitude | lat_deg  | lon_deg     | 
7.371183             | 4.182517               | 7.367983 |4.176017 | 
7.652120             | 4.536282               | 7.648920 |4.529782  |`

Comment: This is what I want to achieve: `resident_latitude | resident_longitude | lat_deg  | lon_deg | distance |
7.371183          | 4.182517           | 7.367983 |4.176017 | 0.85001  |
7.652120          | 4.536282           | 7.648920 |4.529782 | 0.7867   |`

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your question is makes it easier for others to get started.

```
columns = ['resident_latitude' , 'resident_longitude' , 'lat_deg'  , 'lon_deg']

all_rows = ([7.371183, 4.182517, 7.367983 ,4.176017], [7.652120, 4.536282, 7.648920, 4.529782])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=columns)

df
```

```
resident_latitude   resident_longitude  lat_deg lon_deg
0   7.371183    4.182517    7.367983    4.176017
1   7.652120    4.536282    7.648920    4.529782
```

Comment: Thank you very much **Cam** and **Paul H** for your time, efforts and assistance in solving this problem. I was able to solve the problem using **Paul H's** recommendation by replacing the python math module I used with numpy methods.  **Paul H**, could you please write a few expressions to so that I can accept it as what solved the question? I cannot do anything. Thanks once again.